# Chaincode in development mode - Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm following the tutorial "Running chaincode in development mode", there is a note that says " In order to use the DevMode flag on a peer, TLS communications must be disabled on all the nodes in the network" however in the next paragraph it says "No edits are required to the default peer core.yaml or orderer orderer.yaml files." and when i try the tutorial i have this error:
PANI [orderer.common.server] reuseListener -> TLS is required for running ordering nodes of cluster type.
panic: TLS is required for running ordering nodes of cluster type.
And i don't know what should i do